# Что значит выражение "вмешалась третья сила"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Что вообще такое — "третья сила"?
Есть ли какие-нибудь философские (или иные) рассуждения на этот счет?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова зачем тут тире, не могу понять?

Comment: Мне показалось, что так — красивее, чётче, понятнее (с разделением тире). Из текстов: _Что же такое вообще — любовь?_  _Что это такое — ордер на квартиру?_   P.S. Я уже говорила, что доверяю Вашему мнению: если Вы считаете нужным и _правильным_ исправить, — только буду рада _грамотной_ правке.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова примеры эти взяты непонятно откуда) Мне кажется противоестественным ставить тут тире. Но я не уверен на 100 %, что это однозначно неправильно. Вот если Вы найдёте такие примеры у классиков (хотя бы у двух — трёх), это будет убедительнее. :)

Answer (score 1):

В общем смысле: когда есть сила действия, непременно возникает сила противодействия. Гипотетическая третья сила, вмешиваясь по своей только логике в их взаимодействие или противоборство, будет определённо угрожать непредсказуемостью последствий этого процесса.

В математических теориях линейные процессы противопоставляются нелинейным, тектонике в геологии или архитектонике — антитектоника, в  философии логике гармонии — **хаос**, в представлении древнегреческих философов: зияющая бездна.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю про философские размышления, могу сказать, как сама понимаю.

«Третья сила»  - это сторонняя, излишняя сила. Борются  обычно две антагонистические силы,а третья открыто, напрямую не вмешивается, но часто дирижирует, преследуя свои интересы.

Answer (score 0):

Человеку свойственно дуальное восприятия мира (дух и материя, идеальное и материальное, черное и белое, да и нет, добро и зло, и т. п.). В частности, обычно конфликт рассматривается как противостояние двух участников, двух сил. Если обнаруживается, что это не так, говорят о третьей силе. Выражение "вмешалась третья сила" подразумевает, что в конфликте первоначально участвовали две силы, но потом появилась третья, которая, вероятно, изменила ситуацию.